# This webpage has a redirect loop issue with SSL page

Tags: loop, redirect, errors, ssl

I'm having an issue with the code below.

As of right now, my domain is http://www.mydomain.com. When I try to click on the register link, I get an error saying:

```
--This webpage has a redirect loop--

$link2 = '<a href="' . esc_url(site_url('/register')) . '" title="' . esc_attr(__('Register')) . '">' . esc_attr(__('Register')) . '</a>';
```

The register page is an SSL page so it uses the HTTPS protocol.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Your question stands it does not appear to be relevant to WordPress (nor does mydomain.com appear to be running WordPress), and as such may well fall outside the scope of our community as "off-topic." Please review the [ask] section of the Help Center for more information regarding what kinds of questions fit well at WPSE, as well as what goes into writing a good question. If this question is strictly regarding PHP, you may find better assistance posting your question at [webmasters.se] or [so].

Comment: Make sure you aren't caught by the [SSL proxy problem](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/wordpress-is_ssl-doesnt-work-behind-some-load-balancers/). There's a test script in [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) that will tell you if WordPress can detect SSL properly.